# why is the loop for webscraping returning an error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nonetype

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as r
d='https://coreyms.com'
da=r.get(d).text 
print(da)
corey=BeautifulSoup(da,'lxml') 
print(corey.prettify())

for article in corey.find_all('article'): 

    hd=article.h2.a.text
    print(hd) 

    summ=article.find('div',class_='entry-content').p.text 
    print(des)

    vid=article.find('iframe',class_="youtube-player")["src"] #upon inspection, this line of code is not running correctly in the loop. Am i missing something?

    splt_vd_link=vid.split('/')[4] 
    splt_vd_link=splt_vd_link.split('?')[0]
 
    y_link=f'https:youtube.com/watch?v={splt_vd_link}'
    print(y_link)

    print()
```

I am learning how to scrape a webpage by following a YouTube tutorial. My line of code is exactly the same as shown in the tutorial but it returns an error as I run it. I am totally lost

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the **full text** of the error and traceback you are getting.

Comment: `print(des)` or `print(summ)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is printing not existing variable `print(des)` and the second thing is that not every `<article>` tag on page you're trying to **scrape** contains `<iframe>` with youtube link so you need to skip an iteration in loop in this case:

```py
if vid is None:
    continue
```

Full working code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as r
d='https://coreyms.com'
da=r.get(d).text 
print(da)
corey=BeautifulSoup(da,'lxml') 
print(corey.prettify())

for article in corey.find_all('article'): 

    vid=article.find('iframe',class_="youtube-player")
    if vid is None:
        continue
    vid = vid["src"]

    hd=article.h2.a.text
    print(hd) 

    summ=article.find('div',class_='entry-content').p.text

    splt_vd_link=vid.split('/')[4] 
    splt_vd_link=splt_vd_link.split('?')[0]
 
    y_link=f'https:youtube.com/watch?v={splt_vd_link}'
    print(y_link)

    print()
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation. The code worked!!
I am still a little curious about the fact that the same line of code worked in the youtube tutorial.